# Having trouble deleting client

Tags: perforce

I'm getting this error while trying to delete a client named 'test':

> Client 'test' has files opened. To delete the client, revert any opened files and delete any pending changes first. An administrator may specify -f to force the delete of another user's client.

I try `p4 opened` and it shows:

> //TestRepo/test/TestA.java#1 - edit default change (ktext)
>
> //TestRepo/test/TestB.java#1 - edit default change (ktext)

How do I delete these files so that I'm able to delete the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `p4 revert //TestRepo/test/TestA.java //TestRepo/test/TestB.java` from within the client first.

Comment: Thank you jamesdlin. I tried what you suggested and now it says "File(s) not opened on this client" when I type `p4 opened`, which is good. But I'm still unable to delete the client due to this error: `Client 'test' has pending changes. To delete the client, delete any pending changes first. An administrator may specify -f to force the delete of another user's client.`

Comment: @DaoLam: Run `p4 changes -s pending` to get a list of pending changesets for the client, and then run `p4 change -d CLN` to delete each changeset.

Answer (score 0):

You can force delete some files with the administrator setting using services.

Comment: Such a short answer is not high quality.  Can you give more instruction on how to use the administrator setting?